# Error while using public namespace quick_xml::se

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to use the `quick_xml::se::to_string` function. This seems to be a public function, since it is [in the publicly available docs,](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.20.0/quick_xml/se/fn.to_string.html) is marked as pub in the `quick_xml` sources, and seems to [work fine in the `quick_xml` unit tests](https://github.com/tafia/quick-xml/blob/95c924131749f43f458745b8a6a04f8ab80c0c2d/tests/serde_attrs.rs#L7). Here's my code:

```
use quick_xml::se::to_string as xml_to_string;
use serde::{Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Clone)]
struct ApiError<'a> {
    code: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    xml_to_string(ApiError { code: "foo" })
}
```

However, this fails with a

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `quick_xml::se`
 --> src/main.rs:1:16
  |
1 | use quick_xml::se::to_string as xml_to_string;
  |                ^^ could not find `se` in `quick_xml`
```

I've tried a couple other ways of importing this function (`use quick_xml;`, `use quick_xml::se::to_string`) but it seems that no matter what, I get the same error. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use [`quick-xml`](https://crates.io/crates/quick-xml)'s `se` module, you'll need to enable the `serialize` feature.

```
# Before:
# quick-xml = "0.20.0"

# After:
quick-xml = { version = "0.20", features = ["serialize"] }
```

This is mentioned in [`quick-xml`](https://crates.io/crates/quick-xml)'s README if you scroll down to "Serde". It is also mentioned in the docs under ["Features"](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.20.0/quick_xml/index.html#features).

---

Also, [`quick_xml::se::to_string()`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.20.0/quick_xml/se/fn.to_string.html) expects a reference to you need to add `&`, e.g.:

```rust
fn main() {
    xml_to_string(&ApiError { code: "foo" });
}
```